# postgres docker exits with code 1 and exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to spin up a docker img of a postgres db alongside my app.

I am wondering if this is some linux compatibility thing since I am running docker on windows 10?

When I run the command:  docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build
I get all the way to the bottom and fail :

```
Starting testdriven-app_users-db_1 ... done
Recreating testdriven-app_users_1  ... done
Attaching to testdriven-app_users-db_1, testdriven-app_users_1 users-db_1  | 2018-11-06 01:39:05.178 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address"0.0.0.0", port 5432
users-db_1  | 2018-11-06 01:39:05.178 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
users-db_1  | 2018-11-06 01:39:05.198 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
users-db_1  | 2018-11-06 01:39:05.212 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-11-06 01:37:48 UTC
users-db_1  | 2018-11-06 01:39:05.216 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
users_1     | standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
testdriven-app_users_1 exited with code 1
```

here is my yml file:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - "./services/users:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test

    depends_on:
      - users-db

  users-db:
   build:
    context: ./services/users/project/db
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
   ports:
    - 5432:5432
   environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

and my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add netcat-openbsd

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and the subsequent entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z users-db 5432; do
    sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgresSQL started"

python manage.py run --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was dos end of line character is different than linux. My docker container is a linux distro but visual studio code was running on windows. If you go to the bottom right, you can change the EOL for a particular file. I went to entrypoint.sh and changed it from crlf to lf

Comment: Thank you - I ended up stuck on the same issue and this fixed it for me as well!